# Visual Studio: Cannot debug/attach to docker containers - Access is denied

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, visual-studio-debugging

#### Aim

Debug a .Net5 API running on a local docker container.

#### Problem

Visual studio complains that a specific docker command cannot be executed
[image]

#### Things tried so far without resolving the issue

- Run VS as admin
- Gave 'Everyone' permission and removed 'Read only' attribute from the source code and docker folders
- Run the same command ('docker ps ...') from both powerShell and Visual Studio's terminal window --> Worked without any permission issues.
- **Note 1**: The containers are running and functioning as expected
- **Note 2**: Visual studio update --> 16.11.5
- **Note 3**: The issue was observed after a windows update.

Comment: If you only updated Windows and didn’t do any modifications, then the issue I believe is related to the updating(Windows), cache and some settings. Try to delete some cache files, for example `.vs` folder if it exists, and reboot your machine then retry(also try to repair VS). For settings, it will be good to check the configurations set previously and confirm nothing was changed(reset settings if necessary). For Windows issue, what about reporting this to [Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/dockertools/issues)?

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting vs and repairing didn't work either. After some days of research, I gave up and just used IISExpress to attach my application on and debug (changes in configurations to access the other containers using other ports were needed). Definitely not a solution to the problem, but it is a workaround.

Comment: An update here. I gave up since I was not able to find a solution. After some months I tried again to debug and it was just working. My totally baseless guess: one of the many updates which was applied during those months resolved the permission issue.